# Rails 3 login and logout dependent on user cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I want my home page to show the words logout and the path link_to logout_path to show when a user is logged in.

I had this working but have just implemented a remember me radio button and the shift from using user.id to recognise the user to auth_token seems to have messed up my if and else statements. I really can't figure out what I need to change.

I have the following:

Sessions Controller

> ```
> class SessionsController < ApplicationController
> def new
> end
>
> def create
>     user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
>     if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
>         if params[:remember_me]
>         cookies.permanent[:auth_token]
>         else
>         cookies[:auth_token]
>         end
>         redirect_to root_url
>     else
>         flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password!"
>         render "signup"
>     end
> end
>
> def destroy
>     cookies.delete(:auth_token)
>     redirect_to root_url
> end
>
> end
> ```

The Relevant area of my home page:

```
<div class="login">
                <li><% if session[:user_id] %>
                    <!-- user is logged in -->
                    <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %>
                    <% else %>
                <!-- user is not logged in -->
                    <%= link_to "Login", login_path %>
                    /
                    <%= link_to "Sign up", signup_path %>
                <% end %></li>
            </div>
```

My User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_secure_password
before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }

validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
validates_presence_of :email
validates_length_of :email, :within => 6..50
validates_length_of :password, :within => 6..30
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false, :on => :create
validates_format_of :email,    :with => /^[A-Z0-9_.%-]+@([A-Z0-9_]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
                                :message => "must be a valid e-mail address"

def generate_token(column)
begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end

end
```

My Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery

private

def current_user
@current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if  cookies[:auth_token]
end
end
```

Any help people can offer really would be much appreciated as I have tried various different things in my home page and nothing seems to get it showing Logout.

Thanks

Comment: try using <% if current_user %> where you are using <% if session[:user_id] %>

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have just tried `<% if current_user %>` and this doesn't seem to work as it gives me an undefined variable or method error. I also tried `<% if :current_user %>` which fixes the error but then my logout path doesn't actually log out the user. Does anyone know why the action `<% current_user %>` is saying it's un-defined?

Comment: Just to be clear I currently have `<% if session[:current_user] %>` in my pages#home page - this clears the undefined variable error but then when you login the logout button never displays.

Comment: This has now been fixed! To see the full solution go to [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?841726-Log-Out-won-t-work-correctly&s=c8f61a37fb6f494562de1b13e17600e8)